# Assign an unknown number of values to ggplot col params in a for loop R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a ggplot with an unknown number of models. Right now I have a for loop that adds these models to the base ggplot call like this:

```
for (model in params) {
    model_name <- model_names[i]
    plot <- plot + geom_line(data = model, aes(x, y, col = model_name))
    i <- i + 1
}
```

Where model_names is a vector of strings of the model names. I have figure out that it is not working because the model_name variable seems to be assigned to col after the for loop is finished, taking the last value of model_name and assigning it to every geom_line's col tag. Is there any way to do this so that it will make a plot that differentiates all the models with different colors and a nice key that gives all of their names?

**Update:**
I used a melt to get all the models into a nice data frame which automatically creates a column called variable with the column names in it like @Gregor suggested below, eliminating the need for a for loop:

```
library(reshape2)
combined_models <- data.frame(
      rank = 1:nrow(model),
      'Model 1' = model_1_y,
      'Model 2' = model_2_y,
      'Model 3' = model_3_y,
    ) %>%
    melt(id = 'rank')
```

Now I just call

```
plot <- ggplot() +
    geom_line(data = combined_data, aes(x = rank, y = value, col = variable))
```

Comment: Don't do this. Combine your data in a nice tidy format with a `model_name` column and just use standard syntax.

Comment: Where does i come from? There's almost certainly a way to do whatever you're trying to do without a for loop. If you `dput` your data, people can help

Comment: @camille i is just an index. It is instantiated as 1 before the for loop.

Comment: @Gregor the problem is I want to write a function that works for an unknown number of columns, so I can't hard-code the number of geom_lines into the function

Comment: `ggplot` expects long shaped data, so you should pretty much never have to worry about the number of `geom_lines`---creating multiple lines is done by mapping some variable to an aesthetic such as color. `dput` your data and paste a more substantial chunk of your code so folks can reproduce this

Comment: Glad you worked it out. Rather than edit the answer into your question, you should post it as an answer. 24 hours later you can "accept" it, indicating that your problem is solved. (The 24 hour limit is only there when you answer your own question).

Answer (score 0):

I used a melt to get all the models into a nice data frame which automatically creates a column called variable with the column names in it like @Gregor suggested below, eliminating the need for a for loop:

```
library(reshape2)
combined_models <- data.frame(
      rank = 1:nrow(model),
      'Model 1' = model_1_y,
      'Model 2' = model_2_y,
      'Model 3' = model_3_y,
    ) %>%
    melt(id = 'rank')
```

Now I just call

```
plot <- ggplot() +
    geom_line(data = combined_data, aes(x = rank, y = value, col = variable))
```